# Como transferir um workspace TFS para outro usuario

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, team-foundation-server

Galera, preciso enviar meus peddings changes para outro usuário no team foundation, pelo vs15
isso é possível? eu geralmente fazia um shelve e baixava no meu outro pc, porém era o mesmo usuário no caso, o meu... 
Obrigado galera !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No TFVC, é exatamente dessa maneira que se compartilha código entre desenvolvedores! Para fazer isso, siga os passos:

1. O primeiro desenvolvedor faz um shelve normalmente.
2. Em seguida o segundo desenvolvedor irá acessar no Team Explorer, e no menu de contexto (...) do Pending Changes, clique em Find Shelvesets

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3. Na janela que irá abrir, no primeiro campo, com o ícone de lupa, digite o nome do owner do Shelveset que se quer pegar, e a busca irá relacionar todos deste usuário.
   Normalmente se usa o nome de usuário da rede.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3. É só clicar no Shelvetset que se está buscando, irá abrir a tela de detalhes e fazer o unshelve.

Isso é possível por que os Shelvesets não são privados, por isso, procure não colocar coisas que você não queira que outras pessoas vejam!

Comment: Muito bom, achei até melhor ter uma pergunta aqui porque creio eu que muita gente nova com esse versionador nao conheça.. Valeu !

Comment: E pbrigado pela resposta até achei os shelve aq kk